# how to display the value 6.1234567891e-05 as 6.123e-05 in python

Tags: python-2.7

I want to display the value 6.1234567891e-05 as 6.123e-05 using python
I tried using function round().
But its giving me wrong answer.
Please help me with a solution.

Regards,
Sneha

Comment: possible duplicate of [python limiting floats to two decimal points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/python-limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

Comment: Please see the [Python string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use string formatting.

```
n = 6.1234567891e-05
print '%1.3e'%n
```

Take a look at this for a quick reference: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2008-June/062649.html

Answer (score 0):

You can set the number of decimals to print without changing the model of the data but just changing the view. For example if you want only three numbers after the dot you can use:

```
'%.3e' % n
```

#### Example

```
>>> print '%.3e' % 0.000061234567891
6.123e-05
```